# 'XMLBeans' stubs : no setters/getters in request/response objects : empty datatypes?

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, xmlbeans

I've created stubs using -d xmlbeans option. Here is the full command :

```
wsdl2java.bat -u -d xmlbeans -ns2p http://www.sugarcrm.com/sugarcrm=com.sugarcrm.data,http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/=com.sugarcrm.schema.import1,http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/=com.sugarcrm.schema.import2,http://www.w3.org/2004/06/xmlmime=com.sugarcrm.schema.import3 -p com.sugarcrm -uri Sugar\Sugar_V2_E.xml
```

Surprisingly, there are **no getter methods in the 'returned' data types**, which are supposed to be used to get information/results after communicating with the Server. Besides that, there are **no setters to send the server some parameters** to perform basic operations.

[Here is the WSDL file](https://insideview.sugarondemand.com/soap.php?wsdl)

Ex: objects which have **no getters** (no methods at all) : EntryList, EntryListImpl; SelectFields, SelectFieldsImpl; etc.

**Note**: I had to use XMLBeans since Sugar WSDL defines rpc/encoded style.

Please help, I'm blocked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Axis2 doesn't support RPC/Encoded. Using the XMLBeans binding will allow wsdl2java to complete, but it won't generate useful code as you've discovered.

[Here](http://xfire.codehaus.org/Stack+Comparison) is a somewhat out of date comparison of several of the major SOAP stacks, and you can see that RPC/Encoded isn't widely supported. Your best bet is probably to use Axis (not Axis2).